# Convert hashtag # to %23 when clicked

Tags: php, hashtag

```
$html.='<td><a href="'.get_bloginfo('home_url()').'/search/'.'&submit=Search">'.urlencode($result->terms).htmlspecialchars($result->terms).'</a></td>';
```

I've tried urlencode, urldecode, rawurlencode and rawurldecode.  I quite obviously have no idea what I am doing and have spent the last few hours going in circles trying to learn this stuff.

I have a list of search terms prefixed with a hashtag but when clicked, return no results.  When '#' is replaced with '%23' in the address bar, the search works.

Is there an easy fix or do I take up flower arranging as a hobby?

Comment: You're url encoding the text that shows on the link, not the parameters on the url. The only parameter you  have on the url is `submit=Search` so your question makes zero sense.

Comment: You should post the actual url you are trying to request, this does not make any sense as for example the `/` should be a `%2F` if it is part of the query string. And using hashtags is not the best idea to send something to the server as browsers don't send the hashtag and anything after it.

Answer (score 1):

Can always just use `str_replace()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

So if your parameters are in `$result->terms` then just do

```
str_replace('#', '%23', $result->terms);
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of reply.  I havent solved this yet but my gut tells me you have put me in the right direction for learning.

Comment: I surrender.  I've no business getting involved with any of this!  Thank you again.